# Why is multicollinearity a sample phenomenon?

Tags: least-squares, multicollinearity, sample

We say that multicollinearity is a sample phenomenon. That means we postulate the PRF such that each independent variable is bound to have an independent effect on the dependent variable but due to high correlation between the samples, this separate effect might not be estimated because the sample we obtain will have very similar movement; so we will not be able to isolate the effect of one variable keeping other variables fixed.
For example, suppose `cons = B0 + B1*Income + B2*Wealth + u` is our population specification. Now according to our PRF specification, each Income and Wealth will have independent impact on consumption (impact of 1 keeping other fixed, the estimate of regression coefficient here). But because income and wealth will vary together in same directions too much, we won't be able to find samples which are rich enough to be able to isolate this independent impact. Thus we say  the phenomenon is a sample phenomenon.

But the specification itself might be flawed and thus the error of specification of PRF could well be the reason for failure of samples to be rich enough. Then in such a case why blame the "samples" when flaw can very well be in the "Population" itself?
For example, a specification `Y = b0 +b1*X1 + b2*X2 + u` where it is known that X1 and X2 add up to 1 is a flaw of population specification which leads to multicollinearity, then why is it that we blame the sample that we obtain for multicollinearity?

Comment: I have a clarification or two: when you write that "multicollinearity is a sample problem," do you really mean a "small" data sample problem? Or something else? (There's plenty of literature ascribing the roots of collinearity to the amount of information fed into a regression model.)

Comment: Not really. I'm not saying that multicollinearity is specifically a small data sample problem. I'm saying that the way data on two variables are available, it may not be possible to differentiate the separate impact of the independent variable on the dependent variable because the it may not be possible to keep a variable fixed to see the impact of the other variable (The definition of regression coefficient in multiple regression analysis). This may even be in case of large sample (for example in case where two indep variables are perfectly correlated, say a dummy variable trap). @DJohnson

Comment: What is a "PRF"?  Regardless, the overall nature of your question is obscure. Could you be more specific--or cite a reference--about what it means to "blame" something and what "flaw" you are referring to?

Comment: I had the same question about "PRF."  I'm still confused though. "Regression" can refer to widely differing functional forms: parametric or nonparametric, linear or nonlinear, single or multiple, etc. When you write, "it may not be possible to differentiate the separate impact of the independent variable on the dependent variable," it sounds like you're referring to regression with a single IV. Are you really referring to partialing out the separate impact of *multiple* IVs on a dependent variable? In the case of linear regression, that is best captured with partial or semi-partial correlation

Comment: Could it be that separate issues of collinearity and endogeneity are being conflated here?

Comment: I'm not talking about any endogeneity in variables. I'm referring here to a multiple variable linear OLS model. My question is basically that why do we infer that multicollinearity is a sampling phenomenon. (Reference: Damodar Gujarati textbook on basic linear regression). He quotes "Multicollinearity is esentially a sample (regression) phenomenon. When we postulate theoretical or population regression function (PRF), we believe that all variables included in the model have separate or independent influence on the dependent variable. But it may happen that in any given sample that is.. Contd.

Comment: contd.  ..used to test the PRF some or all independent variable are so highly collinear taht we cannot isolate their individual influence on dependent variable. So to speak, our sample lets us down although the theory says that all X's are important. In short, our sample may not be rich enough to accommodate all independent cariables in the analysis."
Now my question is that if we have specified a model such that the independent variables are correlated highly, why is it still considered a sampling phenomenon when actually the problem is in our specification only. @DJohnson

Comment: Now that I understand the question, it's clear that it's a rooted in textbook economic theory and is, therefore, not a topic I feel qualified to answer. While I'm sure there are some CV participants who would be qualified and willing to field this question, CV is really more for purely statistical questions. I don't have anyone to suggest who might be interested. Why not pose the question on Quora, where there is a high concentration of economists and other experts in the field. In particular, Alex Teytelboym might be a good choice.

Comment: @DJohnson Thank you for the help though, now I feel embarrassed that I asked such a question on a platform like CV. and, asked the same question on quora as well, quora is now a days more active for no sense questions such as how does it feels like meeting a celebrity and all! Not hoping for a decent reply on quora!
Thanks for the help though!

Comment: That's true about the questions on Quora...they can be trivial, ridiculous or both. But, there can be some interesting questions with answers, when taken seriously, that can be profound. You have to poke around to find them though. Try directing your question to some of the leading or ranked respondents in Economics.

Comment: If you are really seeking a critique of the Gujarati quote *why not include the quote in the question*? Questions that ask "what did this author mean when he wrote the following" are generally easier to understand and answer than questions that ask, essentially, "why do people say such-and-such that I am not sure I really understand", without actually quoting them.

Comment: I think what you are looking for, roughly, is this: there's a difference between knowing (or postulating) the population regression function (PRF) and knowing (or postulating) the Data Generating Process (DGP) which produces the entire population. If we know the DGP that means we know how all the $X$ variables relate to one another (which means we understand their degrees of correlation or indeed multicollinearity). In this case we would also know the PRF since we'd know how the $Y$ variable is generated. (1/3)

Comment: But we can know, specify, or postulate the PRF without actually knowing the DGP. And in this case we needn't know anything about how correlated the $X$ variables are, just how the $Y$ variable depends on them. (I'm assuming there's no *perfect* multicollinearity here, e.g. you've not fallen for the dummy variable trap). Your regression model "works" regardless of how closely correlated, or not, the $X$ variables are. Even if they are *almost*, but not quite, perfectly multicollinear. In that sense multicollinearity is not a "population problem". (2/3)

Comment: But if you take the same set-up & try estimating coefficients of the PRF using a sample, *then* the multicollinearity becomes an issue. You may find very high standard errors in your estimates (wide confidence intervals, non-significant $t$ values). You can counteract this by increasing $n$ - as you take $n$ to infinity, you're essentially getting closer to capturing the whole population/DGP. Assuming your functional form is correct, you'll find (near as you like) the PRF. Whereas if you have two correlated $X$ variables in a small sample, you often can't prize their effects apart.(3/3)

Comment: @Silverfish I get it now. 
Thank you and sorry for being naive in asking (postulating) the question. That was my first question on CV so I'm new to the concept. Will keep in mind all the formatting mistakes for the next time, Thanks for the help though!